# How to map nested XML fields to CSV?

Tags: java, xml, csv

I know how to do this for simple xml like-

```
<person>
     <age>10</age>
     <weight>20</weight>
</person>
```

will be mapped to CSV as-

```
age,weight
10,20
```

But how to do it for nested tags?
Example: I have following xml-

```
<root>
    <prop1>someValue</prop>
    <prop2>
        <innerProp>
            <property1>value1</property1>
            <property2>
                <subProperty1>value2</subProperty1>
                <subProperty2>value3</subProperty2>
                <subProperty3>value4</subProperty3>
            </property2>
            <property3>value5</property3>
            <property4>value6</property4>
            <property5>
                <subProperty4>value7</subProperty4>
                <subProperty5>value8</subProperty5>
                <subProperty6>value9</subProperty6>
            </property5>
            <property6>value10</property6>
            <property7>value11</property>
        </innerProp>
    </prop2>
</root>
```

What will be its transformation in CSV?
Or this can't be done at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could flatten this by using a dot for each indent you see. This would be the outcome:

prop1, prop2.innerProp.property1, prop2.innerProp.property2.subProperty1, prop2.innerProp.property2.subProperty2, ...